# Dynamic binding on menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I got the following menu-item

```
<MenuItem
    Header="{Binding ChangeSetCache.History">
    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding ChangeSetCache.History}" />
    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
</MenuItem>
```

ChangeSetCache-class looks like this:

```
public class ChangeSetCache : BaseModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChangeSetModel> cache { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChangeSetModel>();

    public string History
    {
        get { return cache.Count.ToString(); } 
        set { }
    }
}
```

(INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented at the basemodel.)

Why does the tooltip updates the binding and the menuitem-header does not? How do i update the menuitem-header as desired?

If i design the menuitem-tooltip like the following the tooltip also doesn't update:

```
<MenuItem
    Header="{Binding ChangeSetCache.History}"
    ToolTip="{Binding ChangeSetCache.History}" />
```

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless here. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource bindings. That said, your property's setter is empty. How do you expect a PropertyChanged event to be fired?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Of course i only need OneWay-binding and do not need to update the source from the view. I will update my question.

Comment: When do you notify or call `OnPropertyChanged("History")`? If you don't call that the UI will not be aware of the property's new value.

Comment: The base-class `BaseModel` will call the method on each property. In another way i tried it with a test-class and somehow it shows the same behaviour: https://pastebin.com/27GLVH11 Inside my ViewModel i do create a property of this class `public Testmodel Testmodel { get; private set; } = new Testmodel();`  and bind it in xaml `Text="{Binding Testmodel.History}"`. Somehow only the tooltip works

Answer (score 0):

```
<MenuItem.Header>
    <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding ChangeSetCache.History, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</MenuItem.Header>
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your help. I allready tried that and suprisingly it doesn't work...